# My JavaScript function not fired/called?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function in my program, if the button is click it should search and redirect to another page:

javascript:

```
 function initContactView() {
    var txtSearch = $("#searchTextField").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "http://swm-wsdl.companyX.net/mobile.asmx/ContactGet",
        data: param = "searchField="+txtSearch+"&office="+localStorage.getItem("office")+"&person="+localStorage.getItem("person")+"&user="+localStorage.getItem("user")+"&organization="+localStorage.getItem("organization")+"",
        success: successContact,
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });

}
```

and in the HTML :

```
<li><a id="btnContacts" data-action="initContactView" data-click="initContactView()">Contacts</a></li>
```

I have used the alerts but one is fired! , I cant seem to find out why?

Pressing F12 shows: `GET http://swm-wsdl.companyX.net/mobile.asmx/ContactGet?searchField=ruan&office=97&person=119&user=531&organization=14 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Use `onClick` and not `data-onClick`

Comment: Or bind it with jQuery : `$("#btnContacts").on('click', initContactView)`

Comment: The error 500 Internal Server Error means the javascript called the server and an error occured in the server, so your error should be in the server, not in your script, are you using any javascript library that handles the data-click attribute?

Comment: @EduardoWada yes i do

Comment: Then your script is correct and your error message comes from the console.log(msg); in the error function, because your server is throwing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onClick="initContactView()"` or `href="javascript:initContactView()"` instead of `data-click="initContactView()"`

Comment: @user3458266: Define "no reaction."  What *does* happen?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you debug this, what code is invoked?  "It doesn't work" isn't a very helpful description of the problem.

Comment: @David no loading, no redirect, F12 shows query string with the 500 internal server error

Comment: @user3458266: Where is the server error coming from?  The AJAX request?  If that's the case then *clearly* the JavaScript code is working because it's sending the AJAX request.  The error is either in the request itself or in the server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

`data-click` is not correct javascript event, you should use [**onclick**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event

```
<li><a id="btnContacts" data-action="initContactView" onclick="initContactView()">Contacts</a></li>
```

Comment: `onClick` not `onclick` please :)

Comment: @nicael, you think, i had copied your simple answer **JOKE**.. and please elaborate your ans, you gave only solution not reason of issue OK

Comment: I was just kidding Girish ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use onclick as proposed before. data-click is arbitrary data not to be handled by event API at all.

Next try to provide an href attribute in your a element for browsers recognizing its linking semantics properly. In that case you should prevent event from triggering its default action, like this:

```
function initContactView( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // your code ...
}
```

Your HTML might look like this then:

```
<a href="#" onclick="initContactView();">Contacts</a>
```

Comment: Tried that and still i click on button and thats that, no reaction no loading ect

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use onclick istead of data-onClick

```
onclick="initContactView();
```

Thank you.